# How to implement pull to refresh on a ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying implement "pull to refresh" on a ListFragment but right now none of the drop in libraries seem to support it. There's no way to detect overscroll on the list fragment that I can see so I'm wondering if anyone has found a means to get this working?

--

Using Christian's tip I used the following for my onCreateView() method.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   PullToRefreshListView listView = new PullToRefreshListView(getActivity());
   mAdapter = new HomeTweetListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.tweet_list_item, tweets);
   listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   return listView;
}
```

Like Christian said you can only do this with a Fragment. Returning anything other than a ListView on a ListFragment errors out.

EDIT:
To clarify I am using [Johan's PullToRefresh library](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I actually make it work using fragments (not `ListFragment`). So it is basically the same, just return the `PullToRefreshListView` from your `onCreateView` method and that's it. It should also work with `ListFragment`; remember that you must return a `ListView` from `onCreateView` if you use `ListFragment` (you can return whatever you want if you use just `Fragment`).

Comment: So could he possible use my method?

Comment: Yeah. Sure... I added another answer just because you did not take into account that he is working with Fragments, so things change a little bit there. Also, he seems to know that there are third-party libraries to do it... so he may already know about the one you suggested.

Comment: I see where you're going with this. I've tried it but Eclipse doesn't like setting a list adapter to a plain old fragment. Is there a remedy for this?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. You set the adapter when creating the PullToRefreshListView. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the issue on github, https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/issues/30

Comment: wow I spent three days on a probkem like this, totally missed returning list view requirement. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Component that Johan has created that adds a pull down to refresh feature..

[Pull-To-Refresh](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)

Main logic is implemented in PullToRefreshListView that extends ListView.

n your layouts you simply add it like this.

```
<com.markupartist.android.widget.PullToRefreshListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: It is my understanding that Johan's code does not currently support listFragment's implementations. See [here](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/issues/30)

Answer (score 0):

It is now fully documented how to use [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) together with [ListFragment](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/ListFragment):

https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/ListFragment

Hope that helps!